# Partioning Linux Filesystem on different NASes

Tags: linux, networking, filesystems, storage, nas

There is a Linux machine that, according to the guy that set it up, has different parts of the Filesystem (I.E. / and /home) allocated on different NASes, resulting in a fictitious display of the actual amount of storage present on the system. (The system says that it has an X amount of storage but in reality, it has less).
Is that even plausible? As far as I know, computers do not lie.
Thanks for clearing this doubt and have a nice day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is possible, there are multiple technologies that can achieve that. The easiest way to access filesystems on a different machine would be [NFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_File_System) or [Samba](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samba_(software)) (with a NAS, you'd probably use NFS, here's [an example of connecting a Synology NAS using NFS](https://kb.synology.com/en-global/DSM/tutorial/How_to_access_files_on_Synology_NAS_within_the_local_network_NFS)). You can also go one layer deeper and use [iSCSI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISCSI) to connect a hard drive to your system over TCP/IP and there are more technologies like this.

Computers of course don't lie, but from an operating system point of view (on the higher or user space level) it doesn't really matter whether the filesystem or disk is connected over network or physically present in the PC -- if it's mounted, it means you can use it. You can always check `/etc/fstab` where you can identify NFS and other network filesystems, instead of device, these will be referred using an IP address and you can check for iSCSI targets using `iscsiadm`.